# Can Animation Nodes extract data from dupli-instances?

Tags: animation-nodes

By dupli-instances I mean dupli(`verts/faces/particles/frames`). I was thinking that once *vertex snapping is working with duplies* in 3d viewport, then you can somehow extract vertex location and poly's in Animation Nodes, like from normal mesh.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think the API provides such access. However, it is very easy to generate this information yourself based on the data already given by blender. For instance, vertex dupli-instances data can be generated as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Similarly, we can do that for polygons, edges, particles, and frames.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see Transform Mesh in my AN 2.1 of 2.79 Blender in Mesh section, only via search bar (moreover there is no "Join Meshes" option?). I assume this node is like "Instancer", but joins all meshes in one object with this checkbox checked?

Comment: @SergeL Not all nodes are available through menus, it will probably be added to the menu soon. The *Join Meshes* option appears when the input matrices are a list. Yes, when your input transformation is a list, it works like this.